# Why does () returns nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, language-features

In Ruby, when you run:

```
()
=> nil
```

The output is `nil`. I don't understand which Ruby mechanism this is using.

I thought it was calling `self()`, but `self()` returns `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting end-of-input`.

Why does this return `nil`, and which language feature is this using?

Comment: `self` is an object. `self()` is asking for a *method* named `self`, which does not exist. `()` is not a method call, it's just grouping "nothing" which is treated as `nil`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"No value" is treated as `nil` in very many places in Ruby:

```
-> { break }.()
#⇒ nil

42 if false
#⇒ nil
```

The same is here: parentheses are redundant but they maintain the code block, the empty one, hence it’s treated as `nil`.

---

With Ruby 2.6+ you might check the AST yourself:

```
main > RubyVM::AbstractSyntaxTree.parse('()')
#⇒ (SCOPE@1:0-1:2 tbl: [] args: nil body: (BEGIN@1:1-1:1 nil))
```

Comment: sry, couldn't walk by :)

Comment: So, it's the same as `begin; end`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, not exactly, due to `begin end` declare a code block and parentheses don’t. But the behaviour and the reason both return `nil` are the same, yes.

Comment: I think `()` does declare a code block, doesn't it? https://repl.it/repls/FrozenVibrantRuntimes

Comment: Oh, indeed, you are right. My bad, I was actually never aware of that.